# How to simulate tab and enter key when enter is pressed, preferably in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, enter

I have found lots of solutions on how to replace enter with tab key, but I need to simulate **tab and enter** on enter, please help:

I have an input field and then a list of links (the list is filtered by the input). When I'm done typing and press enter I want the first link to be "clicked". I assume one way i could do this is by simulating a tab key before the enter key, but how do i do that?

Are there any other alternatives?

This is what i have:

```
    <input type="text" id="search_filter" style="COLOR: #999" onFocus="if (this.value == 'sometext') {this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" name="filter" value="someothertext" />
        <div id="links">    
            <ul>
                <li><a href="someurl">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="someurl">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="someurl">And so on</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: would appreciate if you share some of your code including DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<a href="someUrl">Link</a>

<script>

   $(function(){
           $("#input1").keypress(function(event){
                var ENTER = 13;
                if ( event.which == ENTER ) {
                     $(this).next("a").click();
                     e.preventDeafult();
                     return false;
                }
           })
   })
</script>
```

Comment: i change it. try again please

Answer (score 0):

beware of the difference between **keypress** and **keydown**. Keypress won't fire on some keys. So here's my implementation with jQuery and keydown:

```
editorField.keydown( function(e) {
        switch ( e.keyCode ) {
        //13 for Enter
        case 13:
            saveCell();
            break;

        case 40: //I don't remeber which one of those is 'tab'. 
        case 9: //The other should be right arrow
            cell.parent().next().find('td.value').dblclick();
            return false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } );
```

this is my code for inline cell editing but hopefully you will adapt it to your needs.